# Is there any way to only give power to my SSD (not HDD)

Tags: power-management, ssd, battery

I have a laptop with two drives: an SSD and an HDD. 
For battery-saving purposes, I'd like to only supply the SSD with power (since I only use the HDD when I'm using Windows).

Is there any *simple* way to do this? What will be the effects like on battery-life ?

Thanks

Comment: usually if you don't use your hdd it becomes idle and sleeps itself without impact on the system and once you enter it, it wakes up automatically.

Comment: @JoKeR Yes, but it then is still put on alert and ready to spin up if you open some filebrowser or similar things.

Comment: @PerlDuck You cannot avoid this unless you unplug the power cord to the disk.  Having it completely spin down is as close as it gets.